# Applying Cauchy Residue Theorem to $\int_{C}\frac{e^{z}}{sin^2{z} - 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

For $\int_{C}\frac{e^{z}}{sin^2{z} - 1}$, $C = \{|z|=3 \}$,

this has singularities at $z = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $z = \frac{3\pi}{2}$.

So $Res(f,\frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{e^{z}}{\sin(2z)} = \frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{\sin(\pi)}$

But then we are dividing by $0$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you detail how you worked out $\mathrm{Res}(f,\frac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: If the numerator and denominator are both analytic, then $Res(f, z_0) = \frac{p(z_0)}{q'(z_0)}$

Comment: Yeah, not exactly. See @WSL's answer.

Comment: @Demosthene Sorry, I was mistaken. This only works for Simple poles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29 which these are aren't they?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ has order $1$ poles, also referred to as _simple poles_. However, $\frac{1}{\sin^2 z}$ (and hence $\frac{e^z}{\sin^2 z-1}$) has order $2$ poles. As you point out, your formula only applies to the former case. In this case, you should use the [limit formula for higher poles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles), which is precisely what was done in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your thought process was for the residue calculation. What needs to occur is to compute

$Res(f,\frac{\pi}{2}) = \lim_{z\to \pi/2}(z-\frac{\pi}{2})\frac{e^{z}}{\sin(2z)}.$

Since $e^z$ is well behaved, thew limit of interest is really

$\lim_{z\to \pi/2}\frac{z-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin(2z)}=\lim_{z'\to 0}\frac{z'}{\sin(2z' +\pi)}= -\lim_{z'\to 0}\frac{z'}{\sin(2z')}= -\lim_{z'\to 0}\frac{z'}{2z'-\frac{(2z')^3}{3!}+\cdots}=-\frac{1}{2}.$

Thus,
$Res(f,\frac{\pi}{2}) = \lim_{z\to \pi/2}(z-\frac{\pi}{2})\frac{e^{z}}{\sin(2z)} = -\frac{e^{\pi/2}}{2}.$

Does this clarify?

Comment: Well, I suppose, but I already knew this was the residue. I was more curious why my particular method did not work. Since my singularities are Simple poles, the definition $Res(f,z_0) = \frac{p(z_0)}{q'(z_0)}$ applies.

Comment: I see, well the issue then is that these aren't simple poles...

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the integral as

$$-\oint_C dz \frac{e^z}{\cos^2{z}} $$

Note that there are **double** poles at $z=\pm \pi/2$ within $C$.  ($z=3 \pi/2$ is not within $C$ and therefore does not contribute to the integral.)

The residue at $z=\pi/2$ is therefore given by

$$-\left \{ \frac{d}{dz} \left [\left ( z-\frac{\pi}{2} \right )^2 \frac{e^z}{\cos^2{z}}\right ] \right \}_{z=\pi/2}  = e^{\pi/2}$$

The residue at $z=-\pi/2$ is given by

$$-\left \{ \frac{d}{dz} \left [\left ( z+\frac{\pi}{2} \right )^2 \frac{e^z}{\cos^2{z}}\right ] \right \}_{z=\pi/2}  = e^{-\pi/2}$$

The integral is $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues, or $i 4 \pi \cosh{(\pi/2)} $.